# Button still display in layout for a while after setting it's visibility to View.GONE

Tags: android, listview, button, adapter

My layout includes 1 `ListView` to display list of item and 1 "**Load More**" button below the

`ListView` to load more item. When this button is clicked, I set it's visibility to `View.GONE` and

display Progress view instead. But actually,"**Load More**" Button still display until new items are

added to `ListView`. It looks uncomfortable!

I tried to call `adapter.onNotifyDataSetChanged` but no effect. There is any other way to fix this?

Thanks

My Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="4dip" >
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/loading"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:indeterminate="true" />
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/videoList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/load_more"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

My Code:

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.load_more:
            if (startIndex <= mActivity.mVideoCount[selected_pos]) {
                new loadMoreVideosTask().execute();
            }
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
    }

   private class loadMoreVideosTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
                  onPreExecute{
                     // Hide load more button
                     // Show loading Progress  
                 }
              protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                // Loading data
              }
              onPosExecute {
                  // Update ListView
               }

   }
```

Comment: Is the "load more" thing doing some heavy lifting on the UI thread?

Comment: It looks awfully like you are "loading more" in your UI thread, which blocks everything include hiding the button. An easy way to tell is test to see if you can scroll while this is happening. If it is indeed the case, then you should move the loading code off UI thread.

Comment: If "Load more" is clicked, I call to an AsyncTask to load more data

Comment: YOu can also try to set visibility gone in onPreExecute() of AsynTask, befre going to background, this function will get called.

Comment: this is ridiculous...this question has been asked over an hour and you still haven't added one single line of code...voting to close

Answer (score 1):

I think

`ListView.invalidateViews()`

may do the trick for you. It forces redraw on all child views, including the one containing your button. (Put it after your call to set its visibility to `GONE`.)

As I understand it, `adapter.onNotifyDataSetChanged` would only be appropriate when changing the data underlying the `ListView`.

Edit: Note that this will only work if your button is a child of the ListView, which it may not be.

Comment: I might be wrong but this guys said the button is "below the ListView"...it's not a child view

Comment: You might be right about that. We need some code. Kai's theory may also be right about hogging on the UI thread. Clarified this in the answer. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you set the "loadMore" button's visibility to View.GONE util the listview update its data, check it, please .

Comment: If "Load more" is clicked, I set it's visibility to GONE first then call to an AsyncTask to load more data

Comment: you can put these "// Hide load more button" in front of "  new loadMoreVideosTask().execute();",try it.

Comment: I did it, But no effect, Button still keep displaying until new list is loaded

Answer (score 0):

I tried many ways but nothing changed. So I just simple set Alpha of Load more button to 0. But It's not perfect way because I still can see a blank space which taken by button.